# Oracle SQL - Filter based on two columns matching

Tags: sql, oracle, filter, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

Good morning

I would like to filter out rows based on the values of two columns matching. Both columns are in the same table

Not sure if this can be done in a WHERE clause?

**ID = 12345 and Country is null** anything when those two columns match, removes the row

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

````
DELETE
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    (ID = 12345 and Country is null);
```

# Or in a more "safe" way, use soft delete (adding a new column):

alter table [your table name] add is_deleted varchar2(1) default 'N';

update [your table name]
set    is_deleted = 'Y'
where  (ID = 12345 and Country is null);
````

Comment: Thanks for reaching out so quickly. I maybe didn't make it clear. I don't want to make changes on the database. I would like a statement to extract without those rows

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

where (ID != 12345) or (Country is not NULL) this keeps everything with that id and has a Country, but removes rows where Country is null value